# how to set send premium sms permission to always allow in android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-4.2-jelly-bean

i am facing problem while sending sms on android device from my app.

On Android os 4.2.2, in app info, it is showing me dropdown list for Send premium SMS (with option Ask, Never Allow, Always Allow).

how could i set this setting permanently to always allow by programatically?

Comment: Why should you do this? Premium SMS cost money. It's the user's decision whether he wants to spend that money, so the dialog has a very good reason to be there. You most probably can't mess with it at all.

Comment: yes, but how could i handle thoses cancel/send button callback? Does API provids any callback listeners?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know. I suggest you ask another question for this.

Comment: i have ask the same in another q's
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402043/issue-in-sending-sms-using-smsmanager-sendtextmanager-on-android

Comment: Oh it seems noone replies... Maybe you just need to declare some special permission for your app? I mean apps like GoSms must do it some way, too.

Comment: This looks like atempt to make malware :D

Answer (score 1):

If this was possible it will defy the purpose of warning the user before sending a premium SMS that might cost money.

If you read the [Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)](http://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) you will find that warning the user before sending premium SMS is a requirement that must be fulfilled for any OS implementation to be android compatible, so it is not possible for an app to escape this by setting it programatically.

Android system checks the SMS number against REGEX defined in `/data/misc/sms/codes.xml`, and this warning message will be fired automatically beyond the control of your app.