# issue in sending sms using smsManager.sendTextManager on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.3-jelly-bean

i am sending an sms from my app to server which uses 5 digit mobile number.

on 4.2.2 os, it ask me below popup

**Edited**

Q. How to handle cancel/ok button?

[image: How to handle cancel/ok button?]

Comment: whats wrrong with it ?? Wheres the error ??

Comment: my question is How to handle cancel/ok button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work...

```
switch (getResultCode()) {
     // if cancel pressed then result code is 5
     case 5:
         System.out.println("Message cancelled........");
         break;
    // else if send pressed then result code will be one of these below cases
     case Activity.RESULT_OK:
         break;
     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
        break;
     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
         break;
     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
        break;
     case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
        break;
    }
```